# Overlay (block) or power off iOS on iPad using Xcode/Swift or unicorn pixie dust

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, ios11

Hey all I am just wondering if there were anyone out there that knew how to overlay a screen on top of another one in the way that it blocks the original app from being used? Or would It be possible to power off the iPad via Xcode/Swift?

Reason being is that I am in need to creating an app for my own personal use at home for my kids. I am wanting to place a timer on my phone for when the power is turned off or the program they are currently using is blocked by an overlay.

Since this is for my own personal use the ability to use “private” apis are just fine if there are no public apis that can currently do any of the above. Also, there would be no need to place the app in the apple App Store.

I’m looking to just be able to send restful commands or http commands to a background app that’s running on the iPads and then depending on what I sent, have the iPad do.

So to list what I am trying to find code for:
- way to power off/on the iPad.
- have an overlay that blocks the currently running app on the iPad.
- any other way I can do the above that would be better/easier but has the same outcome that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

iOS Apps are not running in the background, so in general it is not possible to have an app in the background and let it come to foreground without any user interaction. Furthermore it would be possible for the kids to simply close your blocking app and go back to whatever app they have been using before.

I'm pretty sure that it is not possible to write such an app without some strange hacks or jailbreaking the device.

As far as I know, there is no such function within iOS itself to lock the device after a certain time. All timers are related to inactivity.

**Update**

You could register your App for GPS updates, so it will be woken up, every time the GPS coordinates change. Then you could check if the time is over, but your app would still be in the background. You could even pop up an iOS Notification, but that could be dismissed as well. And as I said before, even if your App would come to the foreground, it could simply be closed.

Comment: Not even with the undocumented apis?

Comment: @StealthRT I don't think so. I added an update to my answer with closest solution I could think of.